# New to Linq; need to grab multiple values from single row

Tags: vb.net, linq

I'm trying to retrieve multiple columns from a datatable, but only from a single row -- and then set properties based on those results.  I've figured out how to run multiple queries to obtain single columns at a time, but there must be a way to combine it all into one query.

Here's what I thought might work:

```
Dim colSettingsQry = From r In Me.GridProcColumnSettings.AsEnumerable _
                     Where r("DataFieldNm") = colNm _
                     Select New With _
                     { _
                        .uniqueNm = r.Field(Of String)("UniqueNm").Single(), _
                        .sortExpression = r.Field(Of String)("SortExpression").Single(), _
                        .headerTxt = r.Field(Of String)("HeaderTxt").Single(), _
                        .headerStyleWidth = r.Field(Of String)("HeaderStyleWidth").Single(), _
                        .dataFormatString = r.Field(Of String)("DataFormatTxt").Single() _
                     }

gridCol.SortExpression = From c In colSettingsQry _
                         Select c.sortExpression

gridCol.HeaderText = From c In colSettingsQry _
                     Select c.headerTxt
```

... etc.

I'm guessing there's something pretty obvious that I'm missing - anyone have suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for this:

```
Dim colSettingsQry = ... (your query)
Dim setting = colSettingsQry.FirstOrDefault()

If setting IsNot Nothing Then
    gridCol.SortExpression = setting.SortExpression
    gridCol.HeaderText = setting.HeaderText
    ...
EndIf
```

By `FirstOrDefault` you take the first element of a sequence if there is any, else `Nothing`.

Comment: Thanks a bunch!  That did it; I just had to remove the .Single() from the first query.